# Second Order Partial Differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, problem-solving

[image]

I don't have a clue on how to start this question. I have a feeling I will need to use the Clairaut's theorem:
$f_xy=f_yx$

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Use the chain rule my friend. It is just a change of variables going for Cartesian to polar geometry?

Comment: Use the chain rule to find dz/dx? So Dz/dx x dx/dθ? So I will need to change x=rcosθ to θ=cos^-1(x/r)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to derive the Laplacian in plane polar coordinates given the 2D cartesian form. Start with redefining $z = f(x,y) $ as $z = g(r, \theta) $ and using the chain rule.

I would recommend you begin by computing the partial derivatives $$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}, \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}, \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}, \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} $$

And then using the chain rule to find $$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} $$ and then applying it again to find the second partial derivatives and the answer should pop out.

Comment: Am I going to get a specific value for each of the first order derivative ∂z/∂x?  I have ∂z/∂x=∂r/∂x x ∂z/∂r + ∂θ/∂x x ∂z/∂θ ? So 1/cosθ x ∂z/∂r , what is ∂z/∂r ?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\partial_x z = \partial_x r\partial_r z + \partial_x \theta \partial_\theta z
$$
similarly for $y$
then do it a second time

$$
\partial_{xx} z = \partial_x \left(\partial_x z\right) = \left(\partial_x r\partial_r  + \partial_x \theta \partial_\theta \right)\left(\partial_x r\partial_r  + \partial_x \theta \partial_\theta \right)z
$$

(apologies for my lazy notation) I am also not going any further as it is mechanical from here and you should be able to do it :)

Comment: This makes no sense to me, sorry

Comment: @nickb did you get any further? Ps sorry for the delay.